# Anchor's Download Property is not working on some pages (Gmail)?

Tags: javascript, html, csv, download, anchor

I want to insert this HTML element in some pages:

```
<a download="somedata.csv"
   id="downloadLink"
   href="data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,Col1%2CCol2%2CCol3%0AVal1%2CVal2%2CVal3%0AVal11%2CVal22%2CVal33%0AVal111%2CVal222%2CVal333"
>
    Click Me
</a>
```

In all pages, when I change the dom via plugin or manually in elements inspector, to include this element to page's dom, it works great ! 
But, if I do the same in Gmail pages, the file generated is not named "`somedata.csv`" and the extension is lost "`csv`" !

I tried this in local file, in file uploaded to localhost, and in many external website pages, it works in all except for Gmail pages.

**Why it doesn't work in Gmail pages ? And how to fix this ?**

Comment: According to this page the extenstion goes on the end of the href not within the download property: http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute

Comment: But the href's value, in my case, is data not a file.

Comment: it's the same problem on Facebook pages too, the download filename attribute is ignored

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those who are interested, I solved it using Javascript/Ajax, here's the solution:

Here's the function:

```
var downloadDataURI = function($, options) {
    if(!options)
        return;
    $.isPlainObject(options) || (options = {data: options});
    if(!$.browser.webkit) 
        window.location = options.data;
    options.filename || (options.filename = "download." + options.data.split(",")[0].split(";")[0].substring(5).split("/")[1]);
    options.url || (options.url = "http://download-data-uri.appspot.com/");
    $('<form method="post" action="'+options.url+'" style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="filename" value="'+options.filename+'"/><input type="hidden" name="data" value="'+options.data+'"/></form>').submit().remove();
}
```

And here's how to call it:

```
downloadDataURI($, {filename: "test.csv",data:"data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,Col1%2CCol2%2CCol3%0AVal1%2CVal2%2CVal3%0AVal11%2CVal22%2CVal33%0AVal111%2CVal222%2CVal333"});
```

Comment: filename isn't honored by neither firefox on ubunto or firefox on win8

Comment: Does not work in IE10.  `$.browser.webkit` is not true, so `window.location` is set, and IE displays 'Webpage cannot be displayed'.

Comment: Can you add a solution using vanilla JavaScript? (no jQuery)

Answer (score 3):

In Chrome with JQuery, I try this approach:

```
var dataUri = "data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,Col1%2CCol2%2CCol3%0AVal1%2CVal2%2CVal3%0AVal11%2CVal22%2CVal33%0AVal111%2CVal222%2CVal333"
var filename = "somedata.csv"

$("<a download='" + filename + "' href='" + dataUri + "'></a>")[0].click();
```

I created a temp link and trigger click event on it.
but not sure if other browsers work or not.

Comment: Works great in Chrome. Did you manage to find a solution for firefox?

Comment: appending to the body solves the problem on firefox, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27814048