# JavaScript - export HTML table data into Excel

Tags: javascript, html, excel, export-to-excel

I'm trying to convert HTML tables to Excel, i have tried with a JavaScript function which converts a simple table to Excel, it is working fine. If I have multiple tables how will I be able to add all the table data into the Excel file. here's what I tried. I've created 2 tables and given table index `testTable` and `testTable1`.

How will i pass these 2 table ids to the JavaScript function on click of the button? right now on click of the button only the first table is exported to Excel as I'm passing only `'testTable'`. how will i be able to export multiple tables eg: `testTable`, `testTable1` into Excel?

Here's the JavaScript:

```
<script>

var tableToExcel = (function() {
var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
, template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]>    
<xml>
<x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}
</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions>
</x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets>
</x:ExcelWorkbook>
</xml>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<table>{table}</table></body></html>'
, base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
, format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
return function(table, name) {
if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
}
})()

</script>
```

Here's the HTML part,

```
<table id="testTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>ACP</th>
            <th>OEMCP</th>
            <th>Unix<br>
                NT 3.1</th>
            <th>Unix<br>
                NT 3.51</th>
            <th>Unix<br>
                95</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<table id="testTable1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>ACP</th>
            <th>OEMCP</th>
            <th>Windows<br>
                NT 3.1</th>
            <th>Windows<br>
                NT 3.51</th>
            <th>Windows<br>
                95</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Please let me know, how this can be done?
Thanks

Comment: Can't you use web service for this problem. It will also work without postback.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend another Format method. the John Resig micro-template is a very good and simple tool for do what you need. ([ejohn microtemplating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/))

```
(function(){
  var cache = {};

  this.tmpl = function tmpl(str, data){
    // Figure out if we're getting a template, or if we need to
    // load the template - and be sure to cache the result.
    var fn = !/\W/.test(str) ?
      cache[str] = cache[str] ||
        tmpl(document.getElementById(str).innerHTML) :

      // Generate a reusable function that will serve as a template
      // generator (and which will be cached).
      new Function("obj",
        "var p=[],print=function(){p.push.apply(p,arguments);};" +

        // Introduce the data as local variables using with(){}
        "with(obj){p.push('" +

        // Convert the template into pure JavaScript
        str.replace(/[\r\t\n]/g, " ")
              .split("{{").join("\t")
              .replace(/((^|}})[^\t]*)'/g, "$1\r")
              .replace(/\t=(.*?)}}/g, "',$1,'")
              .split("\t").join("');")
              .split("}}").join("p.push('")
              .split("\r").join("\\'")
              + "');}return p.join('');");

    // Provide some basic currying to the user
    return data ? fn( data ) : fn;
  };
})();
```

It is very simple to use. This allows not only show variables between HTML but also execute JavaScript code

Your template string need some modification to work with this microtemplate.

```
{{for(var i=0; i<tables.length;i++){ }}
    <table>
        {{=tables[i]}}
    </table>
{{ } }}
```

finally only need to select all the tables that appear in your example

```
document.getElementsByTagName("table");
```

you can see how it works http://jsfiddle.net/Scipion/P8rpn/1/

Comment: Thanks a ton Scipion! I just wanted to know if I can do this functionality on click of a html button...I tried with this
<input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel(document.getElementsByTagName("table"),"one")" value="Export to Excel">
but this ain't working....How is it working on jsFiddle? If I implement the same in html I'm not able to get the file on click of the button. Kindly let me know if this is possible.

Comment: try <button id="btn">Download</button> and to add it the click event. function download(){
    tableToExcel(document.getElementsByTagName("table"), "one");
}
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click",download);      http://jsfiddle.net/Scipion/P8rpn/3/

Comment: hey, the file is getting downloaded as 'download.xls'; how can I change the name of the download file?

Comment: In chrome is the default name. For use another name you can use a third party solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912198/anchors-download-property-is-not-working-on-some-pages-gmail/13931279#13931279

Comment: @Scipion I have tried your code in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Scipion/P8rpn/3/) and I can successfully export it in the excel file but there are some unnecessary characters shown after the table. See this [image](http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/f3f9/i2tmma73t6hsccafg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

create a function and pass the tableID to it

```
 function passing_id_to_excel(tableID){ 
  var myTableid =
 document.getElementById(tableID) //remaining code }
```

Comment: How will I pass multiple tableIDs?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a checkbox for each table.  Use javascript to process those that are checked.
2. In case if you just want to convert every table, you could use `$('table').each(function() { do something })`.