# Export a single HTML table from a page to Excel page

Tags: jquery, export-to-excel

I have been trying to add a function under all my existing reports that. the function will need to export a single table from the page and into an excel file.

I found a good solution online but needs some tweaking. This is the solution that I found
[JavaScript - export HTML table data into Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224002/javascript-export-html-table-data-into-excel)

you can see how it works http://jsfiddle.net/Scipion/P8rpn/1/

However, this code is exporting all tables into excel file when the page first loads.

What I need to change it to do is to export a table based on a giving element ID and it need to export when a link is clicked not when a page loads.

This is what I have tried to to do so far but is not working

```
$(function(){

    $('#exp1').click(function(){
        //tableToExcel(document.getElementsByTagName("table"),"First Report");
        tableToExcel(document.getElementsById("testTable1"),"First Report");
    });

     $('#exp2').click(function(){
        tableToExcel(document.getElementsById("testTable2"),"Second Report");
    });
});
```

you can see my code js fiddle in here
http://jsfiddle.net/P8rpn/702/

Answer (score 1):

You need jQuery in your fiddle. Also, the table names do not match what you are trying to get in JavaScript.

http://jsfiddle.net/P8rpn/706/

```
$(function () {

    $('#exp1').click(function () {
        //tableToExcel(document.getElementsByTagName("table"),"First Report");
        tableToExcel($("#testTable1"), "First Report");
    });

    $('#exp2').click(function () {
        tableToExcel($("#testTable2"), "Second Report");
    });
});
```

Comment: Super! one last thing I am not able to figure our how to change the file name to something meanfull? insted of calling it download.xls. how can i name it first_report.xls?