# Make jQuery click anchor work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, cross-browser

I have this script:

```
function downloadIt() {
  var dataUri = "data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,Col1%2CCol2%2CCol3%0AVal1%2CVal2%2CVal3%0AVal11%2CVal22%2CVal33%0AVal111%2CVal222%2CVal333"
  var filename = "somedata.csv"
  $("<a download='" + filename + "' href='" + dataUri + "'></a>")[0].click();
}
```

It works on Chrome but doesn't work on Firefox, without any error on the console. What is the cause and how to fix this?

Comment: I've never seen a download attribute, let alone on an anchor tag.

Comment: `download` attribute sets default name for downloaded content

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Appending the element on the `body` solves the problem, just replace line `3` on the question above into this:

```
// store the element to a variable
var x = $("<a download='" + filename + "' href='" + dataUri + "'></a>");

// append to body
x.appendTo('body');

// click it (download)
x[0].click();

// remove from body
x.remove();
```

It seems that firefox won't execute the click event when the element not attached to the `body`

Comment: Supply a description and this answer would be perfect.